# Is there an way to use the viewport height to trigger classes on Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby, tailwind-css

## Scenario

I'm working on this Gatsby site using Tailwind CSS and there is different types of content. Within the blog, the whole viewport is taken and there's overflow with scrolling options, but in some pages, there's not this much of content so it would need to be scrolled, and I'd like the footer to be fixed on the bottom of the page. Much like an slide on a presentation. The header is always fixed on top.

### "Simple solution"

The simple solution I got was to make two kinds of footers, a fixed and a loose one, that I could simply select while coding the pages, like `<Layout footer="loose">...</Layout>`

### The Issue

Thing is I wasn't really taking account of the viewport size and resolution for the user. In some tests over some browsers, these "kind-of-a-slide-pages" went under the header. 
You can try it on [here](https://www.criptografiaedireito.org.br), but here's a couple screenshots of it.

[image: This page have a fixed footer and a "single slide look", but @ Opera the heading is going under the header]
*This page have a fixed footer and a "single slide look", but @ Opera the heading is going under the header*

[image: In this case, dummy content was inserted so we could test the behavior with longer content and fixed footer]
*In this case, dummy content was inserted so we could test the behavior with longer content and fixed footer*

[image: Same as above, but with a "loose footer".]
Same as above, but with a "loose footer".

### Reaching for a solution

So I'm wondering if I could improve the responsiveness of my website by fetching the rendered height of a page and comparing it to the viewport, so a fixed class would be activated on the footer, making it automated and "smarter". This feature would probably be used for other components as well, but this is the main problem right now.

I've found [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/developing-responsive-layouts-with-react-hooks/) on how to use breakpoints with no CSS, but the target is a fixed width. Anyway, it got me thinking on how I could make a hook that would fetch the rendered height of a page (the container div), compare it to the viewport size and trigger a class that would fix that problem and maybe it would reload that value with screen resizing.

I'm not aware of any approach for this kind of issue, so any thoughts or comments on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to describe a little more clearly what it is you're trying to achieve? Currently it sounds like a problem that would be solved with css.

Comment: Sure, I will try. Let's say that viewport height on machine A is around 700px, while the page content have a height of 480px, with a footer of 200px high. This means a total of 680px which fits completely into the viewport with a gap of 20px. So, in this case, the footer would be fixed on bottom and the content vertically centered in the page.  But if the page content was 820px high, the user would need to scroll down the page and the footer wouldn't be fixed anymore. What I'm thinking about is to fetch the rendered page height to compare it to viewports one and trigger the .fixed class

Comment: I still think you are describing something that css alone can solve. I've added an answer and hopefully it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're probably right. I'm going to test your answer now and reply with the results from there.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<header class="flex-initial bg-gray-700 text-gray-200 p-6">
  my header
</header>
<main class="flex-1 bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 p-6">
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

  <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ol>

  <blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
  </blockquote>

  <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
  </ul>

</main>
<footer class="flex-initial bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 p-6">
  my footer
</footer>
```

Comment: I've tried your solution without sucess unfortunatelly. However, I was able to reach something using CSS as you suggested. It's not automatted but it seems to work fine. I've added the vertical alignment thru .content-end and .content-center tailwind classes. It seems to work better than the previous solution I had. Thanks for your answer!